# Ubuntu installation accuses false RAID

Tags: installation, raid

I'm trying to install a Ubuntu 12.04/Win7 dual boot on my machine (with 2 750GB HDs).

Problem is, during the partitioning, the installation says I'm using RAID, and shows only one HD, with 1.5TB.

I have, however, disabled raid on the setup, and installed Windows 7 only on HD 1, and want to keep Ubuntu to HD 2.

I'm afraid to "resize" the partitions using the installer since that could mess my win7 installation.

I did try to use the alternate installer, but had the same results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a fake raid controller.  Simply disabling the bios support does not get rid of the metadata on the disks that identifies them as members of a raid, so Linux still recognizes it.  When you wanted to stop using the drives in a raid, you should have used the bios raid utility to delete the raid set, instead of just disabling the raid bios.  To erase the old metadata now, (assuming the disks in question are sda and sdb ) run:

```
sudo dmraid -Er /dev/sda
sudo dmraid -Er /dev/sdb
```

Comment: Thanks, and just to make sure, should this leave my win7 installation intact?

Comment: @rOim, correct.